# Después de un setResult y finish, no llama onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar. Se trata de realizar un setResult y finish() para volver a la actividad anterior en "onActivityResult", pero no realiza tal proceso. El contexto es el siguiente (trata de aceptar las condiciones de uso y privacidad):

LoginActivity (comprobar que no están aceptados) -> AcceptTermsActivity (Kotlin) -> dar el botón aceptar -> te devuelve a LoginActivity en onActivityResult (en la teoria)

He estado investigando sobre el tema en la documentación, y aquí en otros posts, pero no consigo una respuesta satisfactoria o la solución.

Cuando llamo a la actividad para aceptar los términos:

```
if (existConditionsUrl() || existPrivacityUrl()) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
               TermsAndConditionsActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("conditionsUrl", urlCondiciones);
               intent.putExtra("privacityUrl", urlPrivacidad);
               startActivity(intent);
```

Os dejo aquí el código dentro de AcceptTermsActivity:

```
var termsTask = AcceptedTermsTask()
var i = Intent()
termsTask.execute()
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //(?¿)
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i)
finish()
```

Y en LoginActivity existe la función onActivityResult, pero hace caso omiso. De momento, juego con la función onResume(), pero es una chapuza.

El detalle de las Class, es que todas son con Java, menos TermsAndConditionsActivity que está hecha con Kotlin. Este problema me está sucediendo en varios sitios, y me gustaría poder aclarar el problema.

En el manifiesto ninguna de las classes que participan tiene el **atributo SingleTop**

Muchas gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el resultado en una actividad tienes que iniciar este con el "startActivityForResult", entonces tiene que cambiar esto:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TermsAndConditionsActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("conditionsUrl", urlCondiciones);
  intent.putExtra("privacityUrl", urlPrivacidad);

  //Cambiar aqui
  startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Mas info [Ativity Result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Answer (score 0):

El problema que es que aunque defines un código de resultado (`resultCode`) para el `Intent`:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i)
```

**debes usar [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))** especificando un código de petición (`requestCode`):

```
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

ya que deseas obtener un resultado cuando finalice, y este resultado se obtiene en el método `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

---

Esta sería la definición de los métodos y puedes determinar la diferencia:

> **[startActivity(Intent intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=es-419#startActivity(android.content.Intent))** : inicia una instancia de la Activity que
>   especificó el `Intent`.
>
> **[startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))** Inicia una
>   actividad que especificaste en el `Intent`, y **para la que deseas un
>   resultado cuando finalice.**
>
> **[onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))** Se invoca cuando una actividad que inició se cierra, proporcionándole el código de solicitud con el que lo inició, el código de resultado que devolvió y cualquier dato adicional de él.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo pruebo como especificáis, funciona, pero la actividad anterior se reinicia, y por lo tanto, si hay algún dato escrito en algún campo se borra. Aquí no tiene importancia, porque no necesito almacenar nada, solo volver a la actividad anterior y llamar a unas funciones para inicializar los datos básicos de la app.

Pero por ejemplo, tengo una situación similar donde la actividad anterior SI necesita ser mantenida, porque el usuario rellena campos, y utiliza un buscador que está en otra actividad. No puedo volver y reiniciar la actividad y perder los datos. En ese caso, necesito realizar alguna instrucción que haga algo parecido a onBackPressed(). Si indicas un setResult() y a continuación finish(), debería volver a la actividad anterior e ir a onActivityResult(). Aquí está la info de la documentación:

setResult
   Added in API level 1
   public final void setResult (int resultCode)
   Call this to set the result that your activity will return to its caller.

```
Parameters
resultCode  int: The result code to propagate back to the originating activity, often RESULT_CANCELED or RESULT_OK
See also:

RESULT_CANCELED
RESULT_OK
RESULT_FIRST_USER
setResult(int, Intent)
```

No especifica que el resultado se devuela en onActivityResult, pero está claro que algo hay que recoger, sea RESULT_CANCELED, OK o FIRST_USER. Incluso si quieres pasar alguna información por el EXTRA, cosa que también falla.

Además, el código hasta ahora funcionaba. Pero añadí código, y aparentemente no toqué nada. No se porque ahora ha dejado de funcionar. Sólo me pasa cuando el intercambio se hace entre actividades una escrita en Java y la otra en Kotlin.

Gracias por vuestros comentarios. Saludos!