# ¿Cómo cambiar la activity de un layout? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout, studio

Sé que la pregunta puede ser un tanto estúpida, pero estoy modificando un proyecto ajeno y por más que busco no consigo hacer que el siguiente botón coja los eventos de otra actividad ajena al a que aparece en el listado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver, me coge los eventos de la actividad ItemDetailActivity. Sin embargo, quiero que me coja los eventos de otra actividad que posee los mismos eventos pero con otro nombre. ¿En dónde tengo que mirar en el proyecto para poder cambiar dichos eventos? He mirado en el código del layout y en el manifest, y no consigo ver ninguna referencia a dicha actividad.

Es el layout de un fragment.

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Revisaste en el mismo layout, en la propiedad `tools:context`? Activa la pestaña `Text` para poder verlo más facilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer si es posible, pero tengamos en cuenta lo siguientes escenarios.

1. **El método que deseas lanzar aun no esta disponible**, por ejemplo. Imaginemos que tu botón esta en el activity A y tu quieres lanzar con este botón un método que se encuentra en un activity B y **este activity B** aun no se inicia. Entonces si tu método que quieres ejecutar desde la activity A esta en la activity B y este mismo método hace cosas con la UI, puede que tu app tenga un crash porque aun no existe el activity B y muchos menos su UI.

Para este caso, puedes utilizar datos que persistan sin importar si el activity exista o no. Por ejemplo `SharedPreferences`. La idea seria cada vez que presionas el botón de la activity A, guardes como un flag que te indique que has presionado este botón y cuando inicies tu activity B, verificas este valor y realizas lo que tienes pensando hacer. De esta manera evitas manipular objetos que no se han inicializado porque tu activity B ya esta creado.

Activity A

```
private void botonDelActivityA(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isPressed", true);
    editor.commit();
    // otro código que quieras agregar
}
```

Activity B

```
@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Antes de realizar estas operaciones iniciativa tu activity
    // con el setContent view o alguna otra cosa que necesita inicializarse
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    bool isPressed = sharedPref.getInt("isPressed", false)
    if(isPressed){
        //Aqui realizar la logica que debería realizar si se presiona el botón
        // desde el activity A


        // Luego de hacer la logica, reiniciamos la variable
         editor.putBoolean("isPressed", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
 }
```

Algunas otras soluciones que puedes utilizar es [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), es una librería que te ayuda para la comunicación no solo con activities sino entre fragments, etc. Este utiliza el patron publish subscriber.
También puedes utilizar el`intent` para mandar datos desde la activity A hacia el activity B. de esta manera cuando presionas el botón del activity A le mandas al activity B una variable que indique que ese botón se ha presionado, si en caso no lo ha presiona mandas esa variable con otro valor.  puedes utilizar un bolleano que cuando es `true` significa que se presiono el botón, y cuando es falso que no se presiono, de esta manera cuando abres el activity B sabes si se presionó o no y haces la logica que deseas. [aqui te dejo un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities)

2. **El método que deseas lanzar si esta disponible** En este caso imaginemos que primero iniciaste con el activity B, luego llamaste al activity A, por lo tanto cuando deseas llamar desde tu activity A a un método del activity B no tendrás problemas.

Para este caso, puedes utilizar el método `startActivityForResult` y `setResult`, básicamente desde tu activity A abres el activity B con `startActivityForResult`. Cuando presionas el botón del activity B, llamas a `setResult` pero ademas le adjuntas una variable de la misma ( a mi parecer boleana) que indique se presiono el botón, de esta manera cuando vuelvas a tu activity A, en el método `onActivityResult`  del activity A lees esa variable y si es true haces la lógica que necesitas, caso contrario no haces nada. [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/281492/despu%C3%A9s-de-un-setresult-y-finish-no-llama-onactivityresult)

Tal vez te puede ayudar a usar interfaces si usas fragments, por si te interesa. La comunicación entre fragments se puede hacer con interfaces

Espero te ayude :)